# Set start and end date for last 30 days ending today

Tags: php, date

I need to generate two dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD example: 2010-06-09

The end date should be today and start date should be today - 30 days.

How can I generate these 2 dates in the above format?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> for the last 30 days so end date is
>   today and start date is **today - 30
>   days**

The **[`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)** is real friend:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('today - 30 days'));
```

Comment: What about if the number of days is inside a variable? `echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('today - '$days_no' days'));`

Comment: The solution to my question is PHP string date + 1 day equals?

$today = date('Y-m-d'); $tomorrow = strtotime($today." +".$i." day");

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple with [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class. You can simply pass the string with the relative expression to the constuctor. When you need to get the date as a string in a specific format use [`format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method.

```
$endDate = new \DateTime();
$startDate = new \DateTime('-30 days');

// when you need to use them simple format as a string:
echo $endDate->format('Y-m-d');
echo $startDate->format('Y-m-d');
```